# How to create a new macOS CorePlot project

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, core-plot

I am very new to programming on the Mac so please forgive the probably stupid question.

I am trying to create a new XCode 10, Swift 4.2 project which uses Storyboard. 
I create a new project and drag `codeplot.xcodeproj` from the downloaded Github `core-plot` version 2.3. I would use the 2.2 version but that does not seem to compile correctly. I then add the `coreplot` framework as a direct dependency.  I drag a custom view object onto the View controller and select `CPTGrahpHosingView`.

This is where I seem to get lost.

Can someone send me instructions on where I went wrong or what I need to do next to get a simple line graph working?  Please remember that I am very new to XCode and Swift.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Would you like to try writing Mac apps in C instead, without the whole XCode development model — just the text editor, Makefile and Clang?

Comment: What error is it giving you?

Comment: @hidefromkgb That wouldn't really result in a _native_ Mac app, though. Unless you're using _Swift_ and Clang (and AppKit), which isn't really that different from using Xcode.

Comment: @SilverWolf You\`re wrong. [Try compiling this](https://github.com/hidefromkgb/msu3-waves/tree/master/macos). It\`s pure C, yet it builds into a full-featured .APP with OpenGL and Retina support.

Comment: @hidefromkgb That is _very_ interesting! But while I admit it may be _possible_ to build an app this way, Swift looks far easier. (:

Comment: @SilverWolf Well, easiness is in the eye of the beholder. I presume @coop\`s programming background is largely compatible with mine, which is why I proposed my approach in the first place. When I attempted to dive into Mac coding the way Apple wanted me to, I realized I could stand neither XCode nor Swift.

Answer (score 0):

There are several example apps included with Core Plot for all of the supported platforms. The Mac *DatePlot* and the iPhone version of *CPTTestApp* apps are written in Swift; the others are all in Objective-C.